# In VueJS, Passing variable instead of string name of component to :is attribute of dynamic component does not work

Tags: vue.js, components

In the code example below (referenced in VueJS Official Site) :

```
<script setup>
import Home from './Home.vue'
import Posts from './Posts.vue'
import Archive from './Archive.vue'
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
 
let currentTab = ref('Home')

const tabs = {
  Home,
  Posts,
  Archive
}

watch(currentTab, (currentTab) => console.log(tabs[currentTab], currentTab))
</script>

<template>
  <div class="demo">
    <button
       v-for="(_, tab) in tabs"
       :key="tab"
       :class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
       @click="currentTab = tab"
     >
      {{ tab }}
    </button>
      <component :is="tabs[currentTab]" class="tab"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.demo {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  user-select: none;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tab-button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.tab-button:hover {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.tab-button.active {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.tab {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
```

taken from

[Code Example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNVNFu2yAU/RXkPqSVYrtdpz2wpFrf9riHvdXTRDBOaG1AgNNWUf59B3BcZ13WxFLEvfdwOOfa3F12b0yx7UVGs4XjVhpPnPC9uauU7Iy2nnzXnSCN1R2ZFWUIAnw2ln9o591Yj9Ex4N7yjdy+UQzxMWhHrGjIfgClEqkU18p5wntrhfI/2YosA+5yFmTMrip1QHi2cqjtsCnqnYdF1BJXw5GV2ldqUSabMIjAi860zAtEhCxquSW8Zc4tq6wWna6ymEdl1XuvsSEE+G3zRluALn/Pw9lXRKqoocpGCH0Sr0AgO00e2B9mKOSJdTaHfcY9FNIjr8tlICX7XxOGb7yV/AkMR02ZnjJIJmS3S9thOnoo03HBuEfINVqvQEGoDJKC/oc3Vhw69iLS3y3KcUtqV4l+YbUoJ11E6PxrG5ZFaGF6J41WPm9YJ9tXShxTLnfCyuZrqK20rYWl5Ma8EKdbWZMLIcSklFtWy95R8sm8xLRhdS3VGolr7LnFX0x3zK6lyr02IBPdNLfScN5R8vmA7XE+NLSCe0oUPMWs3grbtPo5f6GE9V4jiebBydvLSn5GBV8g4OZAOsiFgLwVjR91376vW7nenAIctYJzHkt4MU6jZLRUXtgEZ/xpbXWvakoumuvw/Mt0DrppPp49pmFwYo9uQg+SySN6cR2ed/gifbdnbBggpx2OPR36me5q/JayeZbmRN4xUzw6rTCuIl81FHDzaDoh5DA/QlxlG++No2XpGh7mzaMrtF2XWBW2V15ilgnX5Surn/E9gLjK4rwYOEok0Y0cNwKihf0f51/Qd7yBFo72sHKYoWHknp4/6c4lNXEEj5fvxN0D8zh9z6dO4/sM7snYPp/9MPs/5N//ARljNdU=)

[Code Example Reference on VueJS Official Page](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

... when i pass variable 'currentTab' to :is attribute (instead of tabs[currentTab], as below:

`<component :is="currentTab" class="tab"></component>`

... strangely the component stop showing, despite the fact value of variable 'currentTab' should resolve into the string value of a  Component Name on which we click (like, 'Home', or 'Posts', or 'Archive' as you can see the value of variable that i display using console.log through "watch()" ).

So, the code works only when i pass "tabs[currentTab]" to :is attribute or when i pass the string name of the component (Home, or Posts, or Archive) as below:

`<component :is="Archive" class="tab"></component>` // shows only Archive
OR
`<component :is="tabs[currentTab]" class="tab"></component>` //Shows component w.r.t tab clicked.

If the variable 'currentTab' should resolve into its value to give:

`<component :is="Archive" class="tab"></component>` // shows only Archive

... then why there is strange behavior in resulting view ?

Comment: Please, provide relevant code in the question itself, it should be understandable if external link becomes unavailable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `:is="Archive"` and `:is="tabs[currentTab]"` the value is a component, while in case of `:is="currentTab"` it's a string.

It should either be used with a map of components like `tabs`, or resolved prior to usage:

```
let currentTabComp = computed(() => resolveComponent(currentTab.value))
```

This is [not well-supported by `script setup` syntax](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1564), in order for this to work, the components need to be explicitly registered in [component `components` option with regular `script`](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: Hey, @Estus Flask, do we need `resolveComponent` if we are already importing the components? The example you provided will work without any external API, and simply using  `<component :is="currentTab" class="tab"></component>`

Comment: @NehaSoni I think Estus Flask is using that code snippet only to explain if i want to pass a variable currentTabComp to :is attribute of dynamic component, instead of using map of components like tabs, then how to resolve string name of component stored in variable to the component Object's Name, like from 'Home' to Home.
So, :is should not be used / resolved as :is=" ' Home ' " instead it must be used / resolved as :is=" Home " (without quotation marks for string which means actual Vue's component's object)

Comment: Aah, now clear to me. Thanks for the explanation, @FakharAnwar

Comment: @NehaSoni We do, as said, otherwise :is=" ' Home ' " would result in rendering <home> html element instead of a component. It follows the same semantics as h() function where string types produce html elements

Comment: @Estus Flask
With that, Am i safe ? to deduce that ...

const tabs = {
  Home,
  Posts,
  Archive
}


... automatically resolved into 


const tabs = {
  'Home': Home,
  'Posts': Posts,
  'Archive': Archive
}

Comment: @FakharAnwar Yes, a map of comps is a common approach for other frameworks too

Comment: Thanks, @EstusFlask. Now clear. I got confused because I read that we don't need resolveComponent if we can already import the components.

Comment: @NehaSoni Not exactly, they augment each other. If a comp is not globally registered and not imported, it cannot be resolved by name, so both are necessary like here